# Test Automation for CMS based solution

Tags: user-interface, content-management-system, ui-automation

I am going to work on Adobe CMS (CQ05) & Adobe SiteCatalyst based eCommerce website.

Can you advise-
Where can we automate the tests?
[As for any other CMS based solution, pages tend to be very dynamic & UI based automated record-playback execution can fail because of changes in screen]

Please suggest- where do you see opportunity to automate?
What tools one can used?

I will have access to CMS framework but no access to  the code, testing code is out of scope.

Many Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can script your UI tests with Selenium instead of recording/play mode. Usually you record your scenario to build a test skeleton, then you edit the generated test to rely on elements you are sure to be present during the test (element id, etc.)

Comment: WHat type of tests (say- manual scenarios)  can we automate better & what we shouldn't?

Comment: It's highly dependent on your app. Usually we automate UI tests on core and stable features of the interface where you don't expect to have a lot of changes as the maintenance of those tests is expensive.